# What kind of property does a continuously differentiable function has?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there any differences between a continuously differentiable function and a common function? I want ask this question because I have seen many exercises telling me that f(x) is continuously differentiable.

For example, suppose f(x) is continuously differentiable, and f(0)=0
$$f'(x)+\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=e^x$$
Find out the expression of f(x).

Why do I need f(x) to be continuously differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you have quoted does not make sense if $f$ is not differentiable. If $f$ is differentiable and the integrable (so that the RHS makes sense) then automatically $f'(x)=e^{x}-\int_0^{x} f(t) \, dt$ is continuous. Hence there is no hope of any solution to the equation unless $f$ is continuously diffrentiable.

Comment: Well, if $f$ is a (differentiable) function that is a solution to this equation, it will be continuously differentiable for free, since $$f'(x) = e^x - \int_0^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t,$$ both terms of which are differentiable, by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: But that's not I want to ask initially. I want to know the property of continuously differentiable. I'm sorry to mislead you.

Comment: Well, this example show that $f$ being continuously differentiable is a natural assumption in some problems.

Comment: @TheoBendit We even get fore free that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable ... :)